# Weka API - possible classification output

Tags: java, weka

In `weka.classifier.Evaluation` there is the `toMatrixString()` method, which outputs the confusion matrix like below.

```
  a  b  c   <-- classified as
 50  0  0 |  a = Iris-setosa
  0 45  5 |  b = Iris-versicolor
  0  3 47 |  c = Iris-virginica
```

I noticed classes in this output are taken from the dataset given as  parameter of `Evaluation` constructor.

Is there a way to obtain a list of possible outputs from the `Classifier` object?

Answer (score 1):

The possible output will always be from the the range that it has during the Training Mode. Basically, it will create a data structure

> Status {PASS,FAIL,UNDEFINED}

When you are building a model it will classify based on the values it found on Target index.

So in your case,

> Iris-setosa, Iris-versicolor and Iris-virginica

are the possible outcomes the Classifier Object will have.

If you need more information. Please let me know.

Comment: I know outputs will be in the range that it has in the training set, but I would like to know if it is possible to get possible outputs _from the classifier_. I don't want to check the training set

Comment: hi may be there exists an option but as far as i know according to weka documentation, the classification output will be from the array that you provide at @attribute status {yes,no}. Otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: I read the documentation too.. I hoped that I didn't see the method to use, but it looks like it doesn't exist. I'll keep on looking inside the training or saving the list of possible values of the class attribute

Comment: well you dont have to look anywhere. write a small code if you are using Java Api to convert from into .arff or you can import in weka gui and save that in arff format. Then copt the @attrinute to test file. Rest it depends upon your requirement. what you want.